# Including file from PHP inside dialogbox of jQuery is misleading javascript

Tags: php, jquery, include

I have 3 files (file1.php, file2.php and file3.php). Their contents are given below. When I load **file1.php** it shows *two times* the message of "Hello" in an alert box. But when I include file3.php  before or after dialogbox (which is in **file2.php**) then it shows that message only one times (which is what I want).

Does anybody know where is the problem please?

Thanks.

The content of **file1.php**

```
<?php 
     some operations
     require_once("file2.php");
?>
```

The content of **file2.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var dialogOpts={        
         autoOpen: true,
         modal: false,
         height: "auto",
         resizable: false,
         closeOnEscape: true,
         width: 700,
         position: ["center",30]
       }
       $('#learning_activity_wizard_dialog').dialog(dialogOpts);
   });
</script>
<?php 
     some operations         
?>
<div id="learning_activity_wizard_dialog" title="Learning Activity Wizard" class="dialogbox">
    some content
    <?php require_once("file3.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The content of **file3.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      alert('Hello');
  });
</script>
sometext
```

Comment: in `file2.php` you're missing a closing PHP tag around the include for `file3.php`

Comment: @Kerry. I made error when typing here in stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: Why do you want to have javascript inside of the dialog element? Can you move it elsewhere?

Comment: I am include file3.php inside dialogbox (of file2.php) because file3.php has a lot of coding beside alert("Hello"); and I wanted to separate it in order to make a code more readable. Besides file3.php I have file4.php and file5.php also included inside file2.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When jQuery creates the dialog box, it copies everything in the learning_activity_wisard_dialog div to a new DOM node, including the script tag.

So, the tag runs once when the page loads, then again when the dialog is rendered.  Move your script out of that div, or just use some bool to track whether it's already run or not.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `$('#learning_activity_wizard_dialog').dialog(dialogOpts);` it will run the script again.

If you do not want this to happen, move that script tag **out** of the `div` that will later become a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/uRhQT/

i guess this is your problem, adding script tag inside a html that will load again using jquery.

The solution to this what you have only ... use the script outside the div.

**Reason**: The script tag content is executed when defined inline. So When your dialogbox is shown, the contents are copied to the dialogbox which makes it new inline script. So it gets executed and another alert box is shown.